# Searching a table for the best size (comparing ints)

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

so I will explain what I have done and ask the question at the end.

I must check to see if the food is hot, then from that compare the size (height and weight) of the panniers available to the size of the largest food item and select the quantity of panniers I want

```
if (@HotCold = 'Hot')
begin
-- Success - Select number of panniers
select @FoodID, max(@FoodSize), @PannierSize
-- If the panniersize is greater than 1 t can hold the largest item ???
where ((MAX(@FoodSize) / @PannierSize) > 1 )
select @NumOfPanniers = @PannierSize
end
```

I am still trying to understand how do I first compare all the sizes of panniers to the largest foodsize and then select the number of said pannier to the internal variable @NumOfPanniers

Comment: I think there is a misconception here, @VARIABLES hold *single* values (table variables aside), If there were 50 rows in dbo.Panniers what single values do you expect to be in the variables at the end?  - `max(@FoodSize)` makes little sense for a single value and column and table names cannot be used from variables.

Comment: Thanks for commenting, the values I want are the number of panniers that I need to complete this order (i.e if there is an order for a large amount of food I want to pick a pannier that can hold the largest item (large pizza box) and how many of those panniers do I need) So NumOfPanniers and PannierSize

Comment: Is this a homework question?